# laravel user model not loading

Tags: laravel, autoload

I am doing a simple registration and login in laravel.  I had previously built one taking laravel for a test drive prior to deciding to switch from CI.  Anyway, the first time everything worked great.  Upon reinstalling laravel, my User model does not seem to be loading. I can access User::method() for any properties or methods accessible in the Eloquent base model, but I cannot access any methods or properties declared static in my models/User.php model.

When I try and access a property I get "Access to undeclared static property"

I also tried to set a custom db table name for the users table and the system was not seeing this either.  Not sure why it is loading, and not exactly sure how to check.

The User class is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


public static $rules = array(
    'first_name'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
    'last_name'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    );

    /* All other code in this is the standard code. */
 }
```

The route is as follows

```
Route::get('create', function(){
//include(app_path().'/models/User.php');
print_r(User::$rules);

});
```

If I leave the comments in I get "Access to undeclared static property: User::$rules"

If I take the comments out I get a the anticipated print.

Comment: Now I know something is weird.  If I include "include(app_path().'/models/User.php');" in my route or controller I can now access the added static properties.  This should already be loading as the User model.

Comment: Please show us your code, not seeing how you did things makes this a guessing game.

Comment: Sorry, just put the code up.  First post.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Weird. Copied your very $rules to my own User model and it just worked fine here, as it is supposed to in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably need to run `php artisan dump-autoload` from the command line

Comment: Thanks, I had figured this out already, but yes, was the issue.